# Call component dynamically via string in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to invoke a component via string. The reason is that I have on my DB a text and within that text I have some keys that I want to invoke a component in case they are listed in my app.

I know there is a [`{{component}}`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/defining-a-component/#toc_dynamically-rendering-a-component) helper to invoke components dynamically and I was wonder if could make use here somehow. The example I will post is trivial, but the idea is use more complex components like ember-light-table, for example.

Example:

```
// my-route.hbs
{{my-special-component text=complexString}}

// my-route.js
// the content of the string is never the same, which means the dynamic helpers won't be the same, nor will be at the same place.
let complexString = "This is my complex string {{my-simple-helper text="this will be bold"}}. Etc, etc...";

// my-special-component.hbs
{{formatted}}

// my-special-component.js
formatted: computed('text', function() { 
   // ??
})
```

The output would be:

```
This is my complex string <b>this will be bold</b>. Etc, etc...
```

I've tried using triple brackets but that is only for **< tags >**.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. why not just have your string in your component's template?

Comment: Like, I wanted to insert some special features. For example of one feature: a code snippet with highlightjs. There are some ember addons that do that, but to call them I'd need this...

Comment: insert special features? how do you mean?

Comment: can you provide the code youre working with?

Comment: I changed the example to try to exemplify better what I'm trying to say. For the simple stuff, like my example here, I used regex to replace, but for more complex structures I wanted to use components/functions.

Comment: I think the issue is that with components, ember keeps track of bindings between variables, and the component itself so things can be updated. strings don't work like that. So a different approach is needed, I think.  Is it possible for you to just use a block component?

Comment: Yes, it is. What do you have in mind with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

What if you just made a component that takes a block?

```
{{my-special-component}}
  This is my complex string {{my-simple-helper text="this will be bold"}}. Etc, etc...
{{/my-special-component}}
```

and the template for that would look like:

```
 To show above your complex string
   {{yield}}
   to show below your complex string
```

Comment: No, that won't work... because it won't be always at the same place. The content is dynamic. Like a news article

Comment: can you give a clearer example of what you're trying to do? like, if you're wanting to add syntax coloring, you need a renderer in the place you want to render it. or you need to use an editors api to generate the syntax-highlighted code, and send that to text

Comment: I updated. I think it's not possible as you mentioned in your first comment

Comment: I think _how_ you want to do it is impossible. I don't think the task is impossible though.